# Probabilities about weather forecast

Tags: probability

From keeping data ,meteorologist found that if one day is pouring rain the probability that very next day has pouring rain too is $0.2$  and if one day is sunshine  the probability that very next day has sunshine too is $0.1$

Question : If  $1^{st},January \ \  2019$ is pouring rain day

(i) Find probability that     $4^{th},January \ \  2019$ is pouring rain day.

(ii) If we count any month for 30 days   ,many years later , what is an average of sunshine day  in 3 months interval?

I've tried to write map for probability form $1^{st} $to$ \ 4^{th} $ day and use Bayes' Theorem   ,but for (ii) I really have no idea how to approach  the problem indeed.

I appreciate for any advice and helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I preassume that "pouring rain" and "sunny" are the only options here.

---

Choose some day many years later and let it be the probability on sunshine is $p$.

Then the probability on sunshine the next day is: $$p\times0.1+(1-p)\times0.2$$

There is no reason to think that the probability on sunshine for this next days differs from the probability of the original chosen day so:$$p=p\times0.1+(1-p)\times0.2$$

This allows you to find: $$p=\frac2{11}$$

Number the days in the month with $1,2,\dots,30$ and let $S_i$ take value $1$ if there is sunshine on day $i$ and value $0$ if not.

Then $S=\sum_{i=1}^{30}S_i$ is the number of sunny days in that month and with linearity of expectation and symmetry we find:$$\mathbb ES=\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^{30}S_i=\sum_{i=1}^{30}\mathbb ES_i=30\mathbb ES_1=30p=30\times\frac2{11}=\frac{60}{11}$$

This is the average of the number of sunny days in one month of $30$ days.

To find the average for $3$ of such months then you can just multiply with $3$.